# Drupal with Knockout Javascript

Tags: drupal, knockout.js

I'm trying to get Knockout.js to work with Drupal. Seems like the Knockout calls inside a Drupal template file is not reading any of my Knockout calls. Has anyone gotten these two to work together?

Answer (score 0):

You probably forgot all about this but I got it to work by including the js inline in the footer:

```
$header = array(
 'type' => 'file'
 );

 $footer = array(
 'type' => 'file',
 'scope' => 'footer'
 );


drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'MyTheme'). '/js/knockout.js', $header);


<p>First name: <input data-bind="value: firstName" /></p>
<p>Last name: <input data-bind="value: lastName" /></p>
<h2>Hello, <span data-bind="text: fullName"> </span>!</h2>


 drupal_add_js('var ViewModel = function(first, last) {
     this.firstName = ko.observable(first);
     this.lastName = ko.observable(last);

     this.fullName = ko.computed(function() {
         // Knockout tracks dependencies automatically. It knows that fullName depends on firstName and lastName, because these get called when evaluating fullName.
         return this.firstName() + " " + this.lastName();
     }, this);
 };

 ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel("Planet", "Earth")); // This makes Knockout get to work

 ',
     array('type' => 'inline', 'scope' => 'footer', 'weight' => 1)
   );
```

If you found a way to do it from a file let me know, this is no good having to do it this way.

Edit:  nevermind, it works if you include the file at the footer:

```
drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'MyTheme'). '/js/MyKnockoutScript.js', $footer);
```